# SSAS Distinct sum for connected Fact Table

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I have 2 Fact tables with relations Fact Flight 1:many Fact Cost.
Also I have separate dimensions for Fact Flight and Fact Cost.
I want to make Fact Flight measures to be filtered by Fact Cost dimensions and vice versa.
Is it possible in SSAS?

[image: Dimension Usage]

Comment: I dont see how this would be possible, given there is no common dimensionality. Perhaps add an example of what results you would expect.

Comment: You are right, there is no dimensionality. But as I described these facts are connected 1-many. I resolved it adding connecting dimensionality using the connecting key: Regular for Fact Cost and Fact for Fact flight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I described these facts are connected 1-many. I resolved it adding connecting dimensionality using the connecting key: Regular for Fact Cost and Fact for Fact flight.